# python script is not running in apache

Tags: python, apache, cgi, mod-wsgi

I hosted my python script in Apache server. And configured the `httpd.conf` with the help of this [article](http://csparpa.github.io/blog/2013/03/how-to-deploy-flask-applications-to-apache-webserver.html).

But when I am running `http://127.0.0.1:8080` it says "It works!" but when running my flask script method it says `The requested URL /status was not found on this server.`. 
p.s: I am running it by `http://127.0.0.1:8080/status`. Please help. I searched a lot in google but still I cannot resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What configuration did you add to Apache? Impossible to help if you make us guess.

Comment: I followed this blog , I configured everything mentioned in this blog. http://csparpa.github.io/blog/2013/03/how-to-deploy-flask-applications-to-apache-webserver.html

Comment: Did you replace `/hello` with `/status` in test.py?

Comment: It is not helpful to just point at the blog. Cut and paste your config from your ``httpd.conf``, else we cannot tell whether it is complete or whether you have made any errors. Also indicate what ``Listen`` is set to in the Apache config and whether you are using a ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: It is working now, I forgot to add `application-group=%{GLOBAL}` . Thanks for your response @GrahamDumpleton

Answer (score 0):

added `application-group=%{GLOBAL}` in `WSGIScriptAlias` line. It worked.